# Switching from software Engineer to Game developer

Tags: unity, game-design, software-engineering

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this.

I've been working as a software engineer for 3.5 years so far, mostly web apps, mobile apps, web pages in banking systems, educational, etc but I always wanted to work as a game developer.

Currently I have a university degree in CS, and I'm attending a masters degree in Apps design.

I've very little experience in game dev (only for hobby), some space shooters and some steps in unity, also I took some courses of blender, and did some simple sprites (those 8 bit characters but animate them is a big problem for me atm.) but I've never gone too far.

I know I cannot focus on all aspects of game development, because it is a huge world integrated with different disciplines, but I need to make a portfolio with some of my games at least. (I only have partial prototypes, some of them work, some don't...)

I need some advise of people who are in the game business.

- Which **platform/framework** do you recommend for me ? I already know a bit of **Unity** and I feel pretty comfortable with it. I can get some assets to work with (models/audio, etc), there are some free material in the store, and I have budget to spend on that too if necessary.
- How do game companies hire people? What am I suppose to aim for a job? I mean this is a world full of disciplines and I need to focus in something particular I guess, I'm a senior frontend developer too, so I guess I should focus on coding. I think portfolio is the best way of showing your work.

Any suggestions are welcome! thanks!

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. Unfortunately, this is not the place to ask this - how do I get started & what should I learn questions are not on-topic here. You can learn more about [what is and is not on-topic here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: [Extra Credits: Game Careers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLhyKYa0YJ_5DuIIh7p9FOaR6f-WTTzz_A)